# Neo4J CDI silent failure when changing @ApplicationScoped into @SessionScoped

Tags: jakarta-ee, neo4j, cdi

I migrated my Beans to CDI and I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of Neo4j where it doesn't persist nodes (but correctly completes the transaction) with no indication of any error.

What's even more baffling is that the same call to add a node works when called inside the postCosntructor but doesn't when called from a REST service! (g() is called from another RestService class not shown)

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyNeo4JController implements Serializable
{
   @Inject
   private Neo4JGraph neo4jGraph;
   public MyNeo4JController()
   {
     if (neo4jGraph == null)
        {
            neo4jGraph = new Neo4JGraph();
        }
   }

   @PostConstruct
   void postConstruct()
   {
        f();
   }

   public void f()
   {
     getGraphStorage().addNode("F");
   }

   public void g()
   {
     getGraphStorage().addNode("G");
   }
}

@Singleton
public class Neo4JGraph
{
    private static final String FILESYSTEM_DB = "target/neo4j-db";
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    public void addNode(String name)
    {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try
        {
            Node newNode = graphDb.createNode();
            newNode.setProperty("name", name);
            tx.success();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.failure();
        }
        finally
        {
            tx.finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setUp(String rootUuid)
    {
        if (graphDb == null)
        {
            graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(FILESYSTEM_DB);
            indexManager = graphDb.index();
            index = indexManager.forNodes("indexNodes");
            registerShutdownHook();
            setGraphRootUUIDString(rootUuid);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some arcane incompatibility between CDI and neo4J or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Ok apparently I narrowed down the error by changing @SessionScoped in MyNeo4JController into @ApplicationScoped and now nodes are persisted.
Notice in both cases no error was returned but with SessionScoped no node was added!

Anybody has any idea why? because I cannot keep this class as ApplicationScoped!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the constructor from the SessionScoped bean will solve the problem. With the existing code you're creating a new database each time a new session is created.

Comment: I'm actually creating a new database object using the same database with FILESYSTEM_DB = "target/neo4j-db"; If I remove the constructor from the bean how is the database initialized?

Comment: The GraphDataBaseService instance is the database server instance itself - not just a session or connection. If you use it in an embedded way (as you do) you'll have to keep it as a singleton in your application and enforce proper shutdown when your application stops - best thing would be creating the GraphDataBaseService instance in a PostConstruct method and shutting it down in a PreDestroy method of an ApplicationScoped bean and just returning  the instance to other beans (RequestScoped, SessionScoped, etc. clients) without any further magic. They need proper implementation of transactions.